# How to style an anchor as a button in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

When I use a button, it looks like this in Bootstrap 4:

[image]

`<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</button>`

When I use an anchor instead with the buttons styling, it looks like this:

[image]

`<a type="button" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</a>`

How can I get my anchor to look like a flat button?

Comment: There are predefined styles for `.btn` in BS4. So in order to have the same effect for the anchor tag. You need to override it manually.

Comment: You just need to see the CSS of `button` in Dev tools, and update the CSS of `a` tag accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First of all remove `type="button"` from `<a>`. You need to update css for and write custom css for `<a>` tag.

```css
a.btn {border-radius: .25rem; border: 1px solid transparent; padding: .5rem 1rem; color: #fff; }
a.btn:hover { border-radius: .25rem; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank">Download</button>
<a class="btn btn-primary" target="_blank" href="#">Download</a>
```

Comment: This answer is no longer accurate. No custom CSS is needed. I just hit this issue with upgrade from BS3 to BS4 and removing `type="button"` is all that was required for the anchor tag to match from the original code.

Comment: what about the default button style? there is no `btn-default` anymore in BS4 and one cannot style a anchor tag as default button